# K-ary tree with array implementation in C

Tags: c, tree, inorder

Hi everyone so i got this task to make an adt of non-binary tree which can do  traversals. I messed up the structure from the very beginning but I still can do the post-order and pre-order traversal (i don't know if i did it wrong too, but it works). Now i confused how to do the in-order traversal. My code just doesn't work.

1. This is my data structure

   ```
   typedef char infotype;
   typedef int letak;

   typedef struct {
     infotype info;
     letak parent, firstson, nextsibling;
   } node;

   typedef node tree;
   ```
2. These are how I initialize each node

   ```
     void initNode(tree T[], int k, int i)
     {
       char info;

     printf("Input the node name : ");
     scanf(" %c", &info);
     createNode(T, k, i, info);
   }

   void createNode(tree T[], int k, int i, char value)
   {
     int j;

     if(i == 0)
     {
       T[i].info = value;
       T[i].firstson = i+1;
     }
     else
     {
       T[i].info = value;
       T[i].parent = (i-1) / k;
       T[i].firstson = (i * k) + 1;

       if (i % k != 0)
       {
           T[i].nextsibling = i+1;
       }

       else
       {
           T[i].nextsibling = 0;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. and this is how I try to do the in-order traversal

   ```
   void InOrder(tree T[], int maksimum_array, int maksimum_anak)
   {
     bool Resmi = true;

     int i = 0;

     while(i >= 0)
     {
       if(T[i].firstson < maksimum_array - 1 && Resmi == true)
       {
           i = T[i].firstson;
       }
       else 
       {
           if(Resmi == true)
           {
               printf("%c ", T[i].info);
           }

           if(i = T[T[i].parent].firstson)
           {
               printf("%c ", T[T[i].parent].info);
           }

           if(T[i].nextsibling < maksimum_array - 1 && T[i].nextsibling != 0)
           {
               i = T[i].nextsibling;
               Resmi = true;
           }
           else
           {
               i = T[i].parent;
               Resmi = false;
           }   
        }
      }
    }
   ```
4. And this is my main driver :

   ```
    int main()
    {
      tree pohon[1000];
      int maksimum;
      int maksimum_anak;
      int level;
      int i = 0;
      int count = 0;
      char cari;

      printf("Enter array maximum amount : ");
      scanf("%d", &maksimum);

      printf("\nEnter maximum child of each node : ");
      scanf("%d", &maksimum_anak);

      createTree(pohon);

      for (i = 0; i < maksimum ; i++)
      {
         initNode(pohon, maksimum_anak, i);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < maksimum; i++)
      {
         printTree(pohon, i, maksimum, maksimum_anak);
      }    

      printf("In Order Traversal : ");
      InOrder(pohon, maksimum, maksimum_anak); 
   }
   ```

I've tried another algorithms for the in-order traversal like using recursive. But since i messed up the struct those algorithms just did not work. Thank you before.

Comment: You'll have to first define what you mean by in-order traversal for ternary or higher-ary trees before you can support it.  Does the parent get traversed between *each* pair of successive children?  If not, then between which pair is it traversed?  There are multiple choices.

Comment: i think i mean to traversed the parent right after i got its first son

Comment: It looks like node `i`'s parent is always node `(i-1)/k`, and its `j`'th child (where `0 <= j < k`) is always `(i * k) + j + 1`.  Why do you need the `parent` and `firstSon` fields of `node`?  Your tree is completely defined by an `infotype` array and the number of elements in that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(i = T[T[i].parent].firstson)
```

Should be

```
    if(i == T[T[i].parent].firstson)
```

The former assigns to `i`, the latter compares it.